# How to use wget in C++

Tags: c++, unix

I want to use wget command in c++ program but got stuck.I am not getting anywhere the proper way.

I want to use

```
wget -r -np -A .txt http://www.hackershandbook.org/1000/
```

The url will be several and will be fetched from an output file(Fetching I am able to do)

I tried using

```
string command = "wget -r -np -A .txt" + url;

system((const char*)command.c_str());
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Try with an extra space after .txt, as in `"...-A .txt " + url;`

Comment: _"I tried using"_ And what exactly went wrong?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ :  wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
I am getting this

Comment: `(const char*)command.c_str()` Casting to `(const char*)` is unnecessary here, the `.c_str()` is sufficient.

Comment: @Django Igor gave the right answer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : I followed you no compilation error and I am not getting the output also

Comment: That command with the mentioned is url is supposed to download the text file right? running the command directly in terminal window is working but not through script

Comment: C++ is not a "script", it's a compile language. However, these sort of things are usually much better to do in a scripting language such as Python or Perl.

Comment: Actually I was working on a website directory walkthrough.So I feel like comfortable in c++ for breaking the urls.Now I want to download .txt file the urls.@MatsPetersson do you feel doing this work on python or perl will be easy ?

Comment: If you want to download the files,  use wget with --recursive to download recursively the content of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't know your requirements, you can always use `popen`, and read the result using standard functions like fread.

For more information you can always take a look at http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

Something simple would be:

`FILE* file = peopen("wget -r -np -A .txt http://www.hackershandbook.org/1000/","r");`

...

// use `fread`  with the file descriptor

...

to close it you must use `pclose`

Comment: i did the above mentioned part using ifstream and ofstream and now only accessing the urls using the above mentioned wget command is left

Comment: I think you are missing completely how internet works. Wget creates HTTP request, those request can be of different types(check Http methods, for a full) list, wget will not get you the page, will return the http body content, usually html, but can be other things. You must parse the html message and get information you want of that.

Comment: I agreed but the command which I am trying to use will download all the txt file from the website.That is only my requirement

Comment: wget with --recursive